# Get a group created in one domain from other domain with trust relationship between each other

Tags: powershell, dns, controller, delegates

We have a trust relationship between two domains (classic AD).
Our problem is that we are trying to assign one of our OUs one group which is on the other domain.

We are using `Get-AdGroup` in PowerShell, and it works perfect for groups in the domain controller we are running the script on, but when we try to get the group from the other domain (for example: `Get-AdGroup 'otherdomain\groupinotherdomain'`) it does not find the group.
We have a trust relationship between both domains, and if you do it by hand it is possible to do it easily.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not use `Get-ADGroup group -Server OtherDomainDC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the group from the trusted domain just fine.

```
Get-AdGroup -Server <trusteddomain.tld> -Identity <group>
```

Comment: Great. We didn't miss that! Thanks a lot Justan